# Singleton Creation preference

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

You can create singletons in a variety of ways. I am wondering which is better between these.

```
+(ServerConnection*)shared{
    static dispatch_once_t pred=0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method

    });
    return _sharedObject;
}
```

I could see that this compiles down to something very fast. I would think that checking the predicate would be another function call.
The other is:

```
+(ServerConnection*)shared{
    static ServerConnection* connection=nil;
    if (connection==nil) {
        connection=[[ServerConnection alloc] init];
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Are there any major differences between the two? I know these are probably similar enough to not worry about it. But Just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that the first one uses Grand Central Dispatch to ensure that the code creating the singleton will only be ran once. Which assures you that it will be a singleton.

Also GCD applies threat safeness since as per the specifications each call to the dispatch_once will be performed synchronously.

I would recomend this

```
+ (ConnectionManagerSingleton*)sharedInstance {

    static ConnectionManagerSingleton *_sharedInstance;
    if(!_sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
        dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
            _sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
        });
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {    

    return [self sharedInstance];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;    
}
```

Taken from here http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/objective-c-singleton-template-for-xcode-4/

**Edit:**

Here is the answer to exactly what you are asking
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.jp/2011/04/singletons-your-doing-them-wrong.html

**Edit 2:**

The previous code is for ARC, if you want non arc support add

```
#if (!__has_feature(objc_arc))

- (id)retain {  

    return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release {
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease {

    return self;    
}
#endif
```

(Exactly as explained on the first link)

Finally a really good explanation about singletons:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: In manual retain release, don't bother with all that override nonsense.   It'll just make later refactoring away from being a singleton harder and it is a bunch of extra completely unnecessary code.